# jquery mobile multiple pages MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor

I am just trying to do a simple multiple page with jquery mobile but something with the cache (i think) messes it up.

**this is my Layout: _MobileSwipe.Mobile.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title </title>
    @Html.MetaAcceptLanguage()
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1121/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mobile/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/jquerymobile/css")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    });
</script>
```

**This is my View:**

```
 @model List<ExtremeOnline.Models.BookingDays>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Välj din tid";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MobileSwipe.Mobile.cshtml";
}

<div data-role="page" id="1" class="ui-page">
    page 1
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="2" class="ui-page">
    page 2
</div>

 <script>
        $('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function () {
            var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
            // swipe using id of next page if exists
            if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, 'slide');
            }
        });
        $('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function () {
            var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
            // swipe using id of next page if exists
            if (prevpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, 'slide', true);
            }
        });

    </script>
```

**Here is the form**

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchMobile", "Boka", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input class="searchbutton" id="searchBtn" data-ajax="false" type="submit" data-theme="b" value="Sök bokning" />
            }

        </div>
```

The thing is when i run this, the page's layout i sent the post from is cached and displayed in source code.

Why is the layout cached? What to do?

Comment: Not sure if it has something to do, but there is an extra </div> at the end.

Comment: Also, can you post the whole view as it is in your page?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery mobile relies on the page events for multiple page layouts. instead of using $(document).ready(). Use the Page events listed here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

You can then disable ajax navigation in the mobile init event

```
$(document).on(“mobileinit”, function() { 
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
});
```

you also need to move the data-ajax="false" attribute to the form instead of the input button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchMobile", "Boka", FormMethod.Post, new {data_ajax="false"}))
{
    <input class="searchbutton" id="searchBtn" type="submit" data-theme="b" value="Sök bokning" />
}
```